# Efficiency of C# Find on 1000+ records

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework

I am trying to essentially see if entities exist in a local context and sort them accordingly. This function seems to be faster than others we have tried runs in about 50 seconds for 1000 items but I am wondering if there is something I can do to improve the efficiency. I believe the find here is slowing it down significantly as a simple foreach iteration over 1000 takes milliseconds and benchmarking shows bottle necking there. Any ideas would be helpful. Thank you.

Sample code:

```
                foreach(var entity in entities) {
                    var localItem = db.Set<T>().Find(Key);
                    if(localItem != null)
                    {
                       list1.Add(entity);
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        list2.Add(entity);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: what exactly is `db`?

Comment: if this is entity framework, try loading the set first

Comment: Alex, db is a database context in C# MVC. Lorentz, not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: Why not do a .Any if you are using EF? ForEach will execute the query first and might bring a lot of data

Comment: What do you mean with *"if entities exist in a local context"*? Do you mean if they exist in the database or if they are currently cached in memory by the EF context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found your answers very helpful but here is ultimately how I fold the problem. It seemed .Find was the bottleneck.

```
                 var tableDictionary = db.Set<T>().ToDictionary(x => x.KeyValue, x => x);

                foreach(var entity in entities) {
                    if (tableDictionary.ContainsKey(entity.yKeyValue))
                    {
                        list1.Add(entity);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        list2.Add(entity);
                    }
                }
```

This ran in with 900+ rows in about a 10th of a second which for our purposes was efficient enough.

Comment: The use of `ToLookup` can make this even easier still.

Answer (score 3):

If this is a database (which from the comments I've gathered that it is...)

You would be better off doing fewer queries.

```
list1.AddRange(db.Set<T>().Where(x => x.Key == Key));
list2.AddRange(db.Set<T>().Where(x => x.Key != Key));
```

This would be 2 queries instead of 1000+.

Also be aware of the fact that by adding each one to a `List<T>`, you're keeping 2 large arrays.  So if 1000+ turns into 10000000, you're going to have interesting memory issues.

See this post on my blog for more information: http://www.artisansoftware.blogspot.com/2014/01/synopsis-creating-large-collection-by.html

Comment: Doesn't that do more queries? He is in a loop and you're using the db variable twice?

Comment: Change `Any` to `Where`

Comment: @Thraka No, because now we don't need the loop at all.

Comment: Oh duh. I was just thinking it was replacing the center part. He didn't explain how he finds key, nor why he was cycling entities.

Comment: Sorting Entities - Started At - 01/09/2014 11:38:50.225 AM - 938 Entities

Sorting Entities - Ended At - 01/09/2014 11:41:11.424 AM


This is a quick benchmark of your suggestion I just did with 938 entities. As you can see, it now takes 3 minutes.

Comment: @user3170736 Hmm... I don't know how much I believe those results...  That would imply that each query would take 1.5 minutes.  Which sounds bogus.

Comment: Sorting Entities - Started At - 01/09/2014 12:07:05.477 PM - 938 Entities 
Sort 1  - Started At - 01/09/2014 12:07:05.479 PM
Sort 1 - Ended At - 01/09/2014 12:08:32.655 PM
Sort 2 - Started At - 01/09/2014 12:08:32.657 PM
Sort 2 - Ended At - 01/09/2014 12:09:46.434 PM
Sorting Entities - Ended At - 01/09/2014 12:09:46.436 PM - Ran it again, 2 more times, this is what the data shows.

Comment: Does your benchmark include the connection to the database as well?

Comment: There is no database connection here. It is the local context which is the database cached in memory.

Comment: Do this for me... just in case there is some funny business going on... do JUST `db.Set<T>().Where(x => x.Key == Key)` and see how long it takes. (Don't add it to a `list`)

Comment: I posted my solution below. It helped significantly. Thank you for all of your comments.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the database seems to be the bottleneck? If you want to (effectivly) select data from a database relation, whose attribute `x` should match a `==`-criteria, you should consider creating a [secondary access path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index) for that attribute (an index structure). Depending on your database system and the distribution in your table this might be a hash index (especially good for checks on `==`) or a B+-tree (allrounder) or whatever your system offers you.

However this only works if...

- you not only get the full data set once and have to live with that in your application.
- adding (another) index to the relation is not out of question (or e.g. its not worth to have it for a single need).
- adding an index wouldn't be effective - e.g if the attribute you are querying on has very few unique values.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than querying the DB for each item, you can just do one query, get all of the data (since you want all of the data from the DB eventually) and you can then group it in memory, which can be done (in this case) about as efficiently as in the database.  By creating a lookup of whether or not the key is equal, we can easily get the two groups:

```
var lookup = db.Set<T>().ToLookup(item => item.Key == Key);

var list1 = lookup[true].ToList();
var list2 = lookup[false].ToList();
```

(You can use `AddRange` instead if the lists have previous values that should also be in them.)